# Mongo db doesn't start

Tags: database, mongodb

I have a problem to start my mongodb - I need the db for a nodebb I made the users like the docs of nodebb a was some problems with the mongo before, so I tried to uninstall mongo with a apt commend and getting the uninstall file and then I install the mongo again.

Here is my log

```
root@vmi623675:~# mongod -version
db version v4.0.25
git version: 89306fde6167fa12ea6e30d61e05791e8e214e55
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1j  16 Feb 2021
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distmod: ubuntu1804
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
root@vmi623675:~# systemctl start mongod
root@vmi623675:~# systemctl status mongod
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2021-07-11 11:21:06 CEST; 7s ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
    Process: 1509 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=2)
   Main PID: 1509 (code=exited, status=2)

Jul 11 11:21:06 vmi623675.contaboserver.net systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Jul 11 11:21:06 vmi623675.contaboserver.net mongod[1509]: Unrecognized option: security
Jul 11 11:21:06 vmi623675.contaboserver.net mongod[1509]: try '/usr/bin/mongod --help' for more information
Jul 11 11:21:06 vmi623675.contaboserver.net systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVA>
Jul 11 11:21:06 vmi623675.contaboserver.net systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

root@vmi623675:~# su nodebb
nodebb@vmi623675:/root$ mongod
2021-07-11T11:27:46.411+0200 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2021-07-11T11:27:46.420+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1639 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=vmi623675.contaboserver.net
2021-07-11T11:27:46.421+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.25
2021-07-11T11:27:46.421+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 89306fde6167fa12ea6e30d61e05791e8e214e55
2021-07-11T11:27:46.421+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1j  16 Feb 2021
2021-07-11T11:27:46.421+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2021-07-11T11:27:46.421+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2021-07-11T11:27:46.421+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2021-07-11T11:27:46.421+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1804
2021-07-11T11:27:46.421+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2021-07-11T11:27:46.421+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2021-07-11T11:27:46.421+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2021-07-11T11:27:46.429+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found. Create the missing directory or specify another path using (1) the --dbpath command line option, or (2) by adding the 'storage.dbPath' option in the configuration file., terminating
2021-07-11T11:27:46.429+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] Shutdown started
2021-07-11T11:27:46.429+0200 I REPL     [initandlisten] Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown, waitTime: 10000ms
2021-07-11T11:27:46.429+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2021-07-11T11:27:46.430+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2021-07-11T11:27:46.430+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] Shutting down the global connection pool

2021-07-11T11:27:46.430+0200 I -        [initandlisten] Killing all operations for shutdown
2021-07-11T11:27:46.430+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor
2021-07-11T11:27:46.430+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] Shutting down free monitoring
2021-07-11T11:27:46.430+0200 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Shutting down full-time data capture
2021-07-11T11:27:46.430+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Shutting down the HealthLog
2021-07-11T11:27:46.430+0200 I -        [initandlisten] Dropping the scope cache for shutdown
2021-07-11T11:27:46.430+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2021-07-11T11:27:46.430+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
nodebb@vmi623675:/root$ sudo mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf
[sudo] password for nodebb:
Error reading config file: No such file or directory
try 'mongod --help' for more information
nodebb@vmi623675:/root$ sudo status mongodb
sudo: status: command not found
nodebb@vmi623675:/root$ sudo start mongod
sudo: start: command not found
nodebb@vmi623675:/root$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.0.25
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2021-07-11T11:30:28.126+0200 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:356:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
nodebb@vmi623675:/root$ su
Password:
root@vmi623675:~# /etc/init/mongodb.conf
bash: /etc/init/mongodb.conf: No such file or directory
root@vmi623675:~# nano /etc/init/mongodb.conf
root@vmi623675:~# /etc/init/
bash: /etc/init/: Is a directory
root@vmi623675:~# mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf
Error reading config file: No such file or directory
try 'mongod --help' for more information
```

sorry on my english will love to get help

Comment: the logs clearly says what is wrong: ` Unrecognized option: security`

Comment: Error reading config file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

```
mkdir /data/db
systemctl restart mongod.service 
systemctl status mongod.service
```

You shouldn't run with sudo (store data in a user folder): someone snicking code will be running a NodeJS environment with superuser privileges).

---

In the second example you typed `/etc/mongodb.conf`  but that file does not exist. (it should be `/etc/mongod.conf`).